# Setting Group Radio Buttons from DB using PHP

Tags: php, html, radio-button, smarty

Please can someone help me. It always sets the second radio button to checked irrespective of the value of my variables. The variable `$contact.cont_contactGroup` does return the correct value from the DB.

```
<table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="cont_contactGroup" value="1" <? if($contact.cont_contactGroup=='1'):? checked="checked" <? else:? checked=""?> Customer</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="radio" name="cont_contactGroup" value="2" <? if($contact.cont_contactGroup=='2'):? checked="checked" <? else:? checked=""?> Supplier</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does it even work? you don't seem to be using the right php closing tag

Comment: It doesn't work. I need help.

Answer (score 0):

At first - you should use not `short_open_tags` use `<?php` instead of `<?`

then your code seems to be broken. Take a look at:

**wrong syntax**

```
<? if($contact.cont_contactGroup=='1'):? checked="checked" <? else:? checked=""?>`
```

**right syntax**

```
<?php
if($contact.cont_contactGroup == '1') {
    echo 'checked="checked"'
} else {
    echo 'checked=""'
}
?>
```